# Converting between time zones with Noda Time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, nodatime

I'm currently trying to ensure that our legacy back-end can support resolving date times based on the user's current time zone (or, more specifically offset).  Our servers are in eastern standard time, and most of our date times originate there.  However, for users that are in other time zones, a conversion to their time zone (or, in this case, offset) is needed when retrieving those date times.  Also, date times coming from the user will have to be converted to eastern standard time before persistence on the server.  Given that the front end we are developing is web-based, I am able to retrieve the user's offset in minutes and pass that value into my service layer within the header.  I looked at Noda Time and think it's a great API.  It did force me to think about time in a more refined matter, but I am still not 100% sure that I've properly used it correctly.  Here are the methods that I wrote for the conversions described above.  I've tested them and they seem to work.  Given the scenario above, does this look like a proper use of the library?  Am I thinking about date times properly?

```
public static DateTime ConvertToUtcFromEasternTimeZone(DateTime easternDateTime)
{
    NodaTime.DateTimeZone easternTimeZone = NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("America/New_York");
    ZoneLocalMappingResolver customResolver = Resolvers.CreateMappingResolver(Resolvers.ReturnLater, Resolvers.ReturnStartOfIntervalAfter);
    var easternLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(easternDateTime);
    var easternZonedDateTime = easternTimeZone.ResolveLocal(easternLocalDateTime, customResolver);
    return easternZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
}

public static DateTime ConvertToEasternTimeZoneFromUtc(DateTime utcDateTime)
{
    NodaTime.DateTimeZone easternTimeZone = NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("America/New_York");
    NodaTime.DateTimeZone utcTimeZone = NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetZoneOrNull("UTC");
    ZoneLocalMappingResolver customResolver = Resolvers.CreateMappingResolver(Resolvers.ReturnLater, Resolvers.ReturnStartOfIntervalAfter);
    var utcLocal = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(utcDateTime);
    var utcZonedDateTime = utcTimeZone.ResolveLocal(utcLocal, customResolver);
    var easternZonedDateTime = utcZonedDateTime.ToInstant().InZone(easternTimeZone);
    return easternZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
}

public static DateTime ConvertToUtc(DateTime dateTime, int offsetInMinutes)
{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);
    var convertedDateTime = localDateTime.PlusMinutes(offsetInMinutes).ToDateTimeUnspecified();
    return convertedDateTime;
}

public static DateTime ConvertFromUtc(DateTime dateTime, int offsetInMinutes)
{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);
    var convertedDateTime = localDateTime.PlusMinutes(-offsetInMinutes).ToDateTimeUnspecified();
    return convertedDateTime;
}
```

The idea here is that time zone matters when I'm resolving between UTC time and the time zone in the database.  When I'm resolving between the client time and UTC time then offset matters.

In the future, we can persist UTC time, and this will be easier.  Currently, this solution is a stop gap.

The idea is that we are going to go from...

client -> UTC +/- offset -> UTC -> Eastern Time -> database

database -> Eastern Time -> UTC -> UTC +/- offset -> client

to eventually...

client -> UTC +/- offset -> UTC  -> database

database -> UTC -> UTC +/- offset -> client

Comment: When you say "our servers are in eastern standard time" do you actually mean "our servers are in Eastern time" (varying between EST and EDT through the year)? It makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, Jon. Thanks for the clarification.  I do need to take into account daylight savings.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your first method looks okay, although we don't know what `customResolver` is.

Your second method is a bit off. I'd suggest:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToEasternTimeZoneFromUtc(DateTime utcDateTime)
{
    var easternTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
    return Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(utcDateTime)
                  .InZone(easternTimeZone)
                  .ToDateTimeUnspecified();
}
```

Note that you don't need to look up the Eastern time zone in every method call - just have:

```
private static readonly DateTimeZone EasternTimeZone = 
    DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
```

... then use that everywhere.

Your third and fourth methods aren't what I'd think of as idiomatic - for the third method you should use:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToUtc(DateTime dateTime, int offsetInMinutes)
{
    var offset = Offset.FromMinutes(offsetInMinutes);
    var localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);
    return new OffsetDateTime(localDateTime, offset).ToInstant()
                                                    .ToDateTimeUtc();
}
```

The fourth method seems a bit trickier, as we don't provide everything we should in terms of conversions with `OffsetDateTime`. The code you've used is probably okay, but it would certainly be cleaner if you could use `OffsetDateTime`.

EDIT: I've now added a method to `Instant` to make the fourth method cleaner. It will be part of 1.2.0, and you can use:

```
public static DateTime ConvertFromUtc(DateTime dateTime, int offsetInMinutes)
{
    var offset = Offset.FromMinutes(offsetInMinutes);
    var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime);
    return instant.WithOffset(offset)
                  .LocalDateTime
                  .ToDateTimeUnspecified();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jon.  Honestly, I'm a little unclear concerning how the Resolvers work.  It seemed, based on what I've read, that they can be used to account for daylight savings time.  However, I noticed that you didn't use one in your implementation of ConvertToEasternTimeZoneFromUtc().  I am interested in accounting for daylight savings time for conversions between the database persisted date times and UTC.  I don't have to worry about it for converting between UTC and client date times, as I'm given offset in minutes from the client (which implicitly accounts for it DST).

Comment: Also, the version of the library I have doesn't have Offset.FromMinutes().  So, I've converted it to Offset.FromHoursAndMinutes(0, offsetInMinutes).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that the first method could be rewritten without `customResolver`.

```
using System;
using NodaTime;

namespace qwerty
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var convertedInUTC = ConvertToUtcFromCustomTimeZone("America/Chihuahua", DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine(convertedInUTC);
        }

        private static DateTime ConvertToUtcFromCustomTimeZone(string timezone, DateTime datetime) 
        {
            DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[timezone];
            var localtime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(datetime);
            var zonedtime = localtime.InZoneLeniently(zone);
            return zonedtime.ToInstant().InZone(zone).ToDateTimeUtc();
        }
    }
}
```