# Timezone file + abbrev -> long name (better than CLDR)

Tags: datetime, timezone

(This question is similar to 
[Long form name of timezone in NodaTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085981) but different).

Every timezone file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` has 0 or more timezone 
abbreviations. For example, `America/Chicago` has five abbreviations: 
`CDT`, `CPT`, `CST`, `CWT`, and `EST`. For reference, I found these by doing this:

```
cd /usr/share/zoneinfo 
zdump -v America/Chicago | perl -anle 'print $F[13]' | sort | uniq
```

Each combination of file and abbreviation represents, in some sense, a 
different timezone. For the America/Chicago example, not all of these 
timezones are still in use.

My question: where can I find a list of filename/abbreviation 
combinations mapped to long form timezone names?

The "America/Chicago" section of what I'm seeking may look something like this:

```
Filename Abbreviation Full Name 

America/Chicago CDT Central Daylight Time 
America/Chicago CPT [no longer used] 
America/Chicago CST Central Standrad Time 
America/Chicago CWT [no longer used] 
America/Chicago EST Eastern Standard Time
```

(I'm OK with ununsed timezones not being named).

I'm familiar with CLDR (http://cldr.unicode.org/), but the 
`common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml` file therein appears to be 
nontrivially inaccurate (it's also slightly incomplete, but that's not 
as big a deal). For example, this line (the only line matching `CST6CDT`):

```
<mapZone other="Central Standard Time" territory="ZZ" type="CST6CDT"/>
```

states that the name of the `CST6CDT` time zone is "Central Standard 
Time", which is incorrect.

`CST6CDT` is generically called "Central Time", and is GMT-5 ("Central 
Daylight Time") during daylight savings time and GMT-6 ("Central 
Standard Time") outside of daylight savings time.

Calling it "Central Standard Time" year-round is incorrect. Calling it 
"Central Time" year-round would be acceptable, but it would be nice to 
distinguish between Standard and Daylight time.

I considered looking for an "abbreviation to long name" translator, 
but this wouldn't work because /usr/share/zoneinfo repeats 
abbreviations. For example, "EST" means "Eastern Standard Time" in the 
file "EST5EDT", but "Australian Eastern Standard Time" in the file 
"Australia/Melbourne".

I've considered using `common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml` and then 
replacing 'standard' with 'daylight' if the isdst flag is set for the 
specific instant in time I'm considering, but this seems kludgey.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: CLDR is much more than just the windows mapping file, and the Windows ID is not a display name anyway.  I'll elaborate more in an answer later today.

Comment: Question before I start on the longer answer - What programming language are you working with? If it's Java or C, then the answer is simply to use [ICU](http://icu-project.org) which already consumes the CLDR properly and gives you simple functions to get the generic, standard, and daylight forms of the short and long names.

Comment: And if you're planning on consuming the CLDR directly, then you really should read sections 5, 6, and 7 of [part 4 of the LDML specification](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Contents) thoroughly.

Comment: @MattJohnson Actually, I think I answered my own question in the linked question. Probably should have indicated that here.

Comment: Ok, then go ahead and close this one.  Though I still suggest you read the spec, as it can be more complicated than just reading from a single xml file.  You also have to consider meta zones, overrides, location-based formatting defaults, the hierarchy of locales within a language, etc.  Like I said, use a library if you can.

Comment: In other words - it's harder than you think. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Long form name of timezone in NodaTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25085981/long-form-name-of-timezone-in-nodatime)

Comment: Actually, since I'm just looking for the English names, it wasn't that difficult.

Comment: It's not a simple lookup. You'll only find direct names for those zones that have overrides.  Many zone names are derived from their country names.  Take a look at all of the hoops I had to jump through [in my implementation](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames/blob/master/TimeZoneNames/TimeZoneNames.cs#L75-L211).  You also have to remap for CLDR canonicalization, which can be different than TZDB canonicalization (`Asia/Kolkata` vs `Asia/Calcutta`, etc.)

Comment: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/tz2name.txt (I've pretty much done this already, found the special cases, etc-- I'll look at your implementation too, but I think I've got what I need)